# C++: Calling base class method on derived class member

Tags: c++

I have a naive C++ inheritance class question. I have one base class `Base`, two derived classes `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` and two other distinct classes `A` and `B` which share the names of some methods.

Ideally I would like to design methods in the base class that use the methods of `A` and `B`. My attempt  is the following

```
#include <cstdio>
class A{
    public :
        A(){};
        void speak(){printf("hello A\n");};

};

class B{
    public :
        B(){};
        void speak(){printf("hello B\n");};
};


class Base{
    public:
        Base(){};
        void method(){property.speak();}
        A property;

};


class DerivedA : public Base{
    public:
        using Base::Base;

    A property;

};

class DerivedB : public Base{
    public:
        using Base::Base;

        B property;

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


    DerivedA da;
    DerivedB db;

    da.property.speak();
    db.property.speak();

    // Attempting to call the shared method on the two distinct properties 
    da.method();
    db.method();
}
```

Could you point me to a better design ? I suspect I should use templates but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options with different advantages and disadvantages.

1. You can make the base class a template like this:

```
template<class Property>
class Base{
    public:
        Base(){};
        void method(){property.speak();}
        Property property;

};


class DerivedA : public Base<A>{
};

class DerivedB : public Base<B>{
};
```

It is clear and simple, but notice that `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` in this case have *no common base class*, so you can't, e.g. put pointers to them in the same container.

2. You can use polymorphism.

```
class Base{
    public:
        virtual ~Base() {}
        virtual void method() = 0;

};

class DerivedA : public Base{
    public:
        A property;
        void method() override { property.speak(); }
};

class DerivedB : public Base{
    public:
        B property;
        void method() override { property.speak(); }
};
```

This is a bit more complex, involves some code duplication and requires more resources (to store virtual table e.g.), but now the classes really have a common ancestor.

3. Combine templates and polymorphism

```
class Base{
    public:
        virtual ~Base() {}
        virtual void method() = 0;

};

template<class Property>
class Derived: public Base {
    public:
        Property property;
        void method() override { property.speak(); }
};

using DerivedA = Derived<A>;
using DerivedB = Derived<B>;
```

This is actually option #2, but with no code duplication: we make the compiler generate code for us using templates.

4. Other options. There may be other more specialized options depending on your requirements.